# Is setSelection() intended to call a highlightCallback handler function?

Tags: dygraphs

Like it says in the title:

Is `setSelection()` intended to call a registered `highlightCallback` handler function? My experience is that it doesn't, and I don't have quite enough context to get the same effect by calling the handler function from my own code.

This may qualify as a Dygraphs bug.

Answer (score 1):

dygraphs treats highlightCallback as more of a "mousemove" event than something to do with selections. You should be able to fire the callback yourself when you call setSelection—what context are you missing?